# Can I attach files (PDF) to customer.io REST API?

Tags: email, attachment

I am trying to send an email through customer.io service and I need to attach a PDF to it. Ive seen little documentation about attachments, so I dont know if it is possible.

I am trying this approach

```
{
  name: 'myCampaign',
  data: {
   foo: 'bar',
  },
  attachments: {
   'file.pdf': pdfInB64 
  }
}
```

As the example here: https://gist.github.com/jrallison/3e43c58cb208841caf11

Thank you !!

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to send PDF's as attachments via customer.io. I think one of your issues is that your `attachments` object needs to be nested inside of your `data` object. Ex.

```
{
    "name": "foo_bar",
    "data": {
        "foo": "bar",
        "attachments": {
            "helloworld.pdf": "some base64 encoded pdf here"
        }
    }
}
```

However, one caveat here is that there's a limit to the size of attachments.

Comment: Yes, I realized the limit is really small. So attaching a PDF is almost impossible

Comment: Customer.io released the ability to have attachments up to `16MB`; however, you have to contact their technical support and request them to increase the limit, as the default is set to `100KB`.

You can see the comments I left on this [gist](https://gist.github.com/jrallison/3e43c58cb208841caf11)

Comment: According to customer.io [v1/send/email](https://customer.io/docs/api/app/#operation/sendEmail) The total size of all attachments must be less than 2 MB.

Answer (score 0):

Well, apparently is not possible the way I was thinking about it. For PDF is better to have a link to a host you own

```
<a href="{{event.attached_file}}" target="_blank"><img src="LINK TO THE DOWNLOAD PDF IMAGE" alt="Download your PDF file"></a>
```